# Call to member function result() of non object codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function get_priority($priority_id = "") {
    if ($priority_id == "") {
        $qry = $this->db->get("tm_priority");
    } else {
        $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tm_priority WHERE nt_id = {$priority_id}");
        echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
    print_r($qry->result());
}
```

In my above model function I echo the last_query() for debugging purpose and it's giving me the following result

```
 SELECT * FROM tm_priority WHERE nt_id = 1
```

When I run this query directly into my mysqlyog, it's working fine.

Then what else could be the reason of the error below

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /home/staging/erp/application/models/tasks/task_model.php on line 341
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to check for number of returned rows before outputting it :

```
if($qry->num_rows() > 0){
    print_r($qry->result());
}
```